# React useEffect unmount protection is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios, use-effect

I am doing some async data fetching in useEffect with React to handle user state on page refresh. I am receiving the following error which seems common based on google results:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Based on all the documentation around this, this error is based on potentially updating state when the component has already unmounted. The basic fix suggested for this is to check for a variable status tracking whether the component is still mounted before performing the state update.

However, I have implemented the suggested fix and I still receive the error on page refresh. Any additional guidance is greatly appreciated. The abridged code sample is provided below:

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(undefined);
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    
    axios.get('https://api.endpoint/session', { withCredentials: true }).then(session => {
      if(mounted) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        setUser(session.data);
      }
    });

    return () => mounted = false;
  }, [])
```

Comment: Try answer in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450975/to-fix-cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asynchronous-tasks-in-a-useeffect-cleanup-f/60693711#60693711

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-forked-lz2ho?file=/src/TestComponent.js)):

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(undefined);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    axios.get(props.url, { withCredentials: true }).then((session) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        setUser(session.data);
      }
    });

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, [props.url]);
  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useEffect demo:</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Btw you can make your life a bit easier by using custom hooks to perform async auto-cancellable effects (the network request will be aborted on unmounting):
[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-g5qd7?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [cancel, done, result, err] = useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      return (yield cpAxios(props.url).data;
    },
    { states: true, deps: [props.url] }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>
        {done ? (err ? err.toString() : JSON.stringify(result)) : "loading..."}
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={cancel} disabled={done}>
        Cancel async effect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snipt works fine for me. Your mounted is just a local variable, I don't see you have any code that setting states after the component is unmounted. Are you sure this is the problem area?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. This is currently the only location in my code I leverage useEffect and also if I remove the following 2 calls the error goes away:

setIsLoggedIn(true);
setUser(session.data);

Comment: If you can post the full component code, maybe we can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

I received a suggestion about restructuring my code which fixed this issue for me:

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(undefined);
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    const fetchSession = async () => {
      const session = await axios.get('https://api.endpoint/session', { withCredentials: true });
      if(mounted) {
        setUser(session.data);
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      }
    }
    fetchSession();
    return () => mounted = false;
  }, [])
```

I don't fully understand why this resolves the issue compared to my example, but if anyone else is stuck like I was this may help you.

Also, windmaomao's comment on my post may be a more robust way of doing this, but this worked as a quick fix for now while I get his hook-based version implemented.

Comment: It's unclear why this works and the version in your question does not. Both versions run without problems on my local machine.

Comment: Agreed, it really irks me when I solve a problem without understanding the underlying reason for the fix. I am developing locally as well so perhaps something funky is going on. Based on my research it seems like either version should work fine, but for me the example consistently produced this warning in the console and this new version does not.