# Cleaning up a snapshot with firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I am currently using firestore/firebase for my BAAS and am working on getting some data back from a collection. I have the data rendering and communicating properly however I cannot figure out how to clean up my effect hook properly.

I've read that firestore has a built in way to do it with the onsnapshot function but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the actual API call to the firestore database:

```
  getBuds: async (uid) => {
    try {
      const snapshot = await db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('buds')
        .get();
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error @getBuds ', error);
    }
  },
```

And here is the effect function where it's called:

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .getBuds(user.uid)
      .then((res) => setBuds(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [buds]);
```

Please help me with my cleanup!!! I would really appreciate it

UPDATE** So I have modified the original code using the onsnapshot function and am managing to pull down the data I want from fire store, I am getting each document and pushing each one into an array with this code. However I cant seem to now get this code into the component where I call the "getBuds" method :(

Here is the updated getBuds:

```
getBuds: async (uid) => {
    let unsubscribe;

    try {
      const budData = [];

      unsubscribe = await db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('buds')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            budData.push(doc.data());
          });
          console.log(budData);
          return budData;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error @getBuds ', error);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unsubscribe method from a `onSnapshot` listener:

```
let unsubscribe;

getRealtimeUpdates = function(document) {
        unsubscribe = firestore.collection("collection_name")
            .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                if (doc && doc.exists) {
                    const myData = doc.data();
                    // DO SOMETHING
                }
            });
        });
    }
  
  // unsubscribe:
  
  unsubscribe();
```

For more info, please look at [Firestore unsubscribe to updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157997)

Comment: OP is not using a listener.

Comment: Then there is nothing to clean up.

Comment: I've tried using the onSnapshot method but can't seem to get it to return the data properly versus what I have above

Could you be any more specific in how that would go into my code above?

Comment: can you refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450975/to-fix-cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asynchronous-tasks-in-a-useeffect-cleanup-f Is it helpful?