# How to cancel asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function?

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await, axios

### I am getting this error:

> *index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function.
> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak
> in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous
> tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> at Products (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2779:5)
> at div
> at Home
> at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:246119:5)
> at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:246568:5)
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:246499:15)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:244709:5)
> at div
> at App*

I assume the problem is here:

**Products.js**

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getProdcuts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          category
            ? `http://localhost:5000/e-mart/products?category=${category}`
            : `http://localhost:5000/e-mart/products`
        );
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
    getProdcuts();
  }, [category]);
```

My home page is not loading. No problem is shown in the terminal. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450975/to-fix-cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asynchronous-tasks-in-a-useeffect-cleanup-f) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AbortController` to abort an async request, it'd look like

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const getProdcuts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          category
            ? `http://localhost:5000/e-mart/products?category=${category}`
            : `http://localhost:5000/e-mart/products`,
          { signal: abortController.signal } // Notice this line here
        );
        setProducts(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
    getProdcuts();

    return () => {
      // Function returned from useEffect is called on unmount
      // Here it'll abort the fetch
      abortController.abort(); 
    }

  }, [category]);
```

That's a quick way to fix this problem but if you're not sure why this problem is happening in the first place it's probably because you're not expecting `Products` to unmount.
You might have a parent component rendering `Products` or one of its parents conditionnally and a state change cause an unmount before fetch is done.

Comment: Well, I've two parent components which are rendering `Products`. One is `Home` and another one is `ProductList`. The `Home` componet doesn't send any prop but  `ProductList` send 3 props `{categories, filter, sort}`. And I am having this problem while rendering` "/home"` or `"/products"`. But no problem while rendering `"/products/${category}"`

Comment: Is `Products` rendered conditionnally in `Home` or `ProductList`?

Comment: No, there is no condition in `Home` or `ProductList`. But  I am fetching data conditionally which you can see in the code. I've resolved my problem with your code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hook called [`useAbortSignal`](https://github.com/yairEO/react-hooks/blob/master/hooks/useAbortSignal/useAbortSignal.js) and use in any component you're using `fetch` API.

This will automatically abort any ongoing *fetch* when the component unmounts, without needing to write `new AbortController()` unmount logic for every component. DRY.

https://github.com/yairEO/react-hooks/tree/master/hooks/useAbortSignal

```js
export const useAbortSignal = () => {
    const controller = useMemo(() => new AbortController(), [])
    useEffect(() => () => controller.abort(), [])
    return consroller.signal // returns a boolean
};
```

#### Usage:

```
import useAbortSignal from 'hooks/useAbortSignal'

const MyComp = () => {
    const signal = useAbortSignal()

    // fetch initial component data
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/getData', {signal})
            .then(res => ...)
    }, [])

    // ...component logic
}
```